# Using Composite Keys with Salat and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

I've just read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882797/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-compsite-keys-when-using-salat-with-mongodb) on how to use composite keys with Salat and MongoDB... and it is more or less clear how it works. Nevertheless, I'm wondering if the `@Key` annotation is mandatory even if my key is already named `id`. I'm trying to serialize a few case classes coming from an external library and I'd prefer not to redefine them. Given the following external case classes:

```
case class UserId(id: String, mail: String)
case class User(id: UserId, name: String, surname: String)
```

Would it be possible to serialize an `User` object like this (i.e. without the `@Key` annotation)?

```
object UserDAO extends SalatDAO[User, UserId](...)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB expects every document in a collection to have an id field called "_id".  If you fail to provide a "_id" field, then the mongo-java-driver will create one for you.

So what you need to do is either:

- name the field "_id", not "id"
- use `@Key` annotation to remap your "id" field to "_id" when `User` is serialized
- add a global key remapping of "id" to "_id" so that it is not necessary to use `@Key` in place

When dealing with an external model, option three is the most efficient.  See the section "Global Key Remapping" in this wiki article:
https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/CustomContext

Once you've made this remapping, `UserDAO` should work fine with the composite key.

Remember that even if your field is named "id" in the `User` case class, queries *must* refer to `_id` because this is what the field is called in your MongoDB document.

Also, remember that when you use a composite key you're going to need to create a custom index that covers all the fields of your composite key *in the order* for which you are going to query for them.  You can use Dex to analyse your MongoDB log and make recommendations:
https://github.com/mongolab/dex