# Ensuring indexes with MongoDB using Salat DAOs

Tags: indexing, salat, mongodb-scala

There is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934146/using-composite-keys-with-salat-and-mongodb) on composite keys using Salat, but information on ensuring indexes (from mongo-db console, `db.collection.ensureIndex({someField : 1})`) is lacking. Looking through Salat source, I didn't see an annotation for marking a field as needing an index, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by directly accessing the `MongoCollection` from within the DAO object yourself (see: [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-salat/DdI-jM3S4Oo)). E.g.:

```
object AlphaDAO extends SalatDAO[Alpha, Int](collection = MongoConnection()("test_db")("test_coll")) {   
  val beta = new ChildCollection[Beta, Int](
    collection = MongoConnection()("test_db")("test_col1_subcol1"),
    parentIdField = "alphaId") {}

  import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
  collection.ensureIndex(DBObject("some.field" -> 1, "anotherField" -> 1))

  beta.collection.ensureIndex(DBObject("some.field" -> 1, "anotherField" -> 1))
}
```